# Android: what is the best way to store rectange coordinates in database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, rectangles

I have around 100+ rectangles and each rectangle in android is represented by the coordinates of its 4 edges(top, left, bottom, right). Thus, I am wondering if I should store each of these coordinates separately (in different columns) in the SQLiteDatabase or if there is any way by which I can do it differently(say store the whole rectangle) in a much simple way?

**Edited**
What I am looking for is, if there is any other way which can simply store the `Rect` object itself instead of storing `left`,`top`,`right`,`bottom`.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by storing separately ? In separate columns or separate tables??

Comment: store using separate collumn

Comment: Yes, I meant store using separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's any other way than one of those two:

- Storing **X**, **Y** of one corner and **X**, **Y** of the diagonally opposite corner
- Storing **X**, **Y** of one corner and **width**, **height**

In either case, you should store it as one record per rectangle in one table

Comment: Agreed. Which one of the two you choose should depend on what your intent is with the data imho. If you look at the `Rect` documentation in android you'll see that it takes `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` as parameters to its constructor, hence the first option may be best suited for this particular case.

Comment: Well, thanks but I am aware of both the option that is mentioned, but I am wondering if there is any other way which can simply store the `Rect` object itself instead of storing `left`,`top`,`right`,`bottom`.

Comment: No, I don't think there's any better option. Rectangle is an abstract object and what you're storing is its representation. In this case - a set of 4 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your business logics.
Will you need to select rectangles and sort them by their width / heights? 
If yes, store width and height as separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just store the object in the database. You have to store the object's state/data when you write and construct new object (or change an existing one) with the data you read from the database. If there is something already implemented that stores the `Rect` for you it's probably implemented this way. It should be easy to implement it yourself too.